# Using '' and & When updating T-SQL table Query correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax for updating this T-SQL table.

Here is my query which is adding an additional ' at the beginning and end.

Query:

```
  Update [denodo].[dbo].[wrappers]
  SET wrapperWhereClause = '''
  AND County_Input = ''Cheyenne & Arapaho Tribal Court'' 
  AND WrapperID = 729'''
  WHERE wrapperID = '729'
```

The Outcome here is:

```
'AND County_Input = 'Cheyenne & Arapaho Tribal Court' AND WrapperID = 729'
```

The Outcome I am hoping for:

```
AND County_Input = 'Cheyenne & Arapaho Tribal Court' AND WrapperID = 729
```

Can anyone help me edit this so I can receive the outcome I am hoping for?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [denodo].[dbo].[wrappers] 
SET wrapperWhereClause = 'AND County_Input=''Cheyenne & Arapaho Tribal Court'' AND WrapperID=729' 
WHERE wrapperID = '729'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [denodo].[dbo].[wrappers]
SET wrapperWhereClause = 'AND County_Input=''Cheyenne & Arapaho Tribal Court'' AND WrapperID=729'
WHERE wrapperID = '729
```

Comment: I post this on the microsoft forum and received the answer.